# How can I improve this algorithm for a variation of the unbounded knapsack in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, knapsack-problem

The problem is a variation of the unbounded knapsack problem, where you have items of equal value but different weights. This algorithm solves the problem, but I would like to optimize its performance. Does anyone have any recommendations?

```
def knapsack(capacity, bars)
    if capacity == 0 || bars.nil? || bars[0].nil?
        return 0
    end

    solutions = []
    sum = 0
    (1..capacity).each do |i|
        break if sum > capacity
        bars.combination(i).lazy.each do |comb|
            sum = comb.reduce(&:+)
            solutions << sum
        end
    end

    solutions.select{|i| i <= capacity}.max
end
```

Comment: Do you really want `sum` from the final iteration of `bars` to compare to `capacity`? I don't know the algorithm. Just asking. Maybe `bars` is arranged a certain way.

Comment: Bars can be any combination of postive integers. For example, 4 1 1 2 1. Each integer represents the weight of the object, they all have equal value. The capacity in this case could be 7.